# Mongodb index doesn't use one bound in range query

Tags: mongodb

I have such document structure in my collection:

```
{
    "deviceId" : "9113",
    "data" : { 
        "qIdx" : 106 
        "points" : [ 
            { "eDate" : "2013-06-10T00:00:13.000Z" } ,
            { "eDate" : "2013-06-10T00:00:14.000Z" }
        ]
    } , 
    "rdate" : { "$date" : "2013-05-30T22:25:04.359Z"} , 
    "_id" : { "$oid" : "51a7d1c0debcab563502cc41" }
}
```

I have index:

```
{deviceId: 1, data.points.eDate: 1}
```

When I do the query like:

```
{
    deviceId: "9113", 
    data.points.eDate: {
        $gt: "2013-05-11T00:00:00.000Z",
        $lt:"2013-05-12T00:00:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

Index doesn't use one bound - this is explain:

```
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor deviceId_1_data.points.eDate_1" ,
    "nscanned" : 4015 ,
    "nscannedObjects" : 4015 ,
    "n" : 10 , "millis" : 8297 ,
    "nYields" : 103 ,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0 ,
    "isMultiKey" : true ,
    "indexOnly" : false ,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "deviceId" : [[ "9113" , "9113"]],
        "data.points.eDate" : [
            [ "2013-05-11T00:00:00.000Z" , { }]
        ]
    }
}
```

My mongodb version is 2.0.7

Comment: Your $lt and $gt arguments have the same value, so what would you expect your bounds to be? I would also strongly recommend you upgrade to the latest MongoDB version (2.4.4).

Comment: Fixed that, just a typo

Comment: Ok, let me try. I am pretty sure this has been vastly improved in 2.2/2.4 though.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried it and getting the same result. I suggest you ask this on the Google Groups mailinglist (feel free to tell them I've send you there): https://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user

Comment: You got same result in 2.0.7 or in the higher version?

Comment: I've tried it with 2.4.4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with using both index bounds is that a document could have one eDate that satisfies the $gt and another eDate that satisfies the $lt. Because the sematics of your query would match that document it must look at more docs than it would if it used both index contstraints.

There are to things that can help in these types of cases: $elemMatch (see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/)  and cursor.min / cursor.max (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/cursor.min/).

Comment: I did just check, and with elemMatch: db.so.find( { deviceId: "9113", 'data.points' : { $elemMatch: {  'eDate': { $gt: "2013-05-11T00:00:00.000Z", $lt:"2013-05-12T00:00:00.000Z" } } } } ).explain(); --- still gives the same output

Comment: @Derick about to go to sleep but I think that SERVER-6050 is what's needed, or a slightly different schema where the eDates are an array for $elemMatch to work in this specific case, but hopefully cursor.min / cursor.max will work. There are some limitations with min/max like SERVER-3766 but I think it should be ok in this case.